# "For 30 years" vs. "about 30 years"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, time

A company celebrates its 30th anniversary.

If I write:

> - For 30 years, at your service.
> - For 30 years, the best solution.

is that correct?

Or maybe it should be:

> - About 30 years, at your service.
> - About 30 years, the best solution.

Comment: Why the, comma?

Comment: **About** means unsure how many years, roughly 30 years; while **for** means surely 30 years, confirmed.

Answer (score 3):

`About` implies uncertainty about the subject it's quantifying. Therefore, I wouldn't use it in a commercial slogan (which looks like what you're trying to put together here?)

> For 30 years, at your service.
>
> For 30 years, the best solution.

I'm assuming you're using the comma to create some kind of slogan-drama? In any case, the first one here is valid considering your needs, and the second one is borderline valid (Think of how the 2nd slogan would sound *without* the comma). Both sound somewhat unusual.

Answer (score 3):

You might swap the clauses around to give phrases such as

> At your service for [over] 30 years.
>
> The best solution for [over] 30 years.
>
> Serving you for [over] 30 years.